# How to store a word using read()?

Tags: c, arrays, linux, string, fcntl

**About the program:**
Hello, I am writing a simple program to extract content from a .txt file and convert that content into a .csv file. The plan is to look for specific words within that .txt file. This is really just to experiment with the functions open(), read() , write() and close() in C on linux.

**The Problem:**
On line 34 of the code, I try to store each character coming in to form a word. After extracting a " " from the .txt, it will clear the word buffer.
Problem is, I get a segmentation fault (core dump). I am not sure how to fix  This problem. I tried using GDB to debug and find the seg fault at line 34.

Thank you in advance

**The Code**

```
/* 
Program to convert content inside a .txt file 
into a .csv file.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>      // open()
#include <unistd.h>     // For read(), write() an close()
#include <string.h>     // Used for strcmp()

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int samp = open("sample.txt", O_RDONLY);        // This is Opening a file to work with. @param char  *filename,  @param int  access,  @param int  permission
    int csv = open("sample.csv", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0600);     // Used to create a file. 

    char *word;         // Stores each word 
    char buff[1];       // Holds 1 character of the file
    int i = 0;          // Counter for word buffer

    /* read(handle (file), buffer, size (bytes)) */
    /* write(handle (file), buffer, size (bytes)) */

    while(read(samp, buff, 1) != 0){    // Loops through file, char by char 
        printf("%s", buff);             // prints current character in buff

        if(strcmp(buff," ") == 0){      // To create csv, every " " found, we add a "," 
            write(csv, ",", 1);         // If " " is found, we write a comma to csv file
            word = "";                  // Clear word buffer
        }

        else{
            write(csv, buff, 1);        // Write value of buff in csv file
            word[i] = buff[0];              // Copy each characer in buff to word
        }

        i++;
    }

    close(samp);    // Closig .txt file
    close(csv);     // Closing .csv file

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%s", buff);` expects `buff[]` to be a null character terminated character array, a _string_.  It is not.  `strcmp(buff," ")` will not work either for the same reason.

Comment: The affronts to both the language and several standard library function usages in this code are *numerous*.

Comment: Why are you using `open` and `read` rather than `fopen` and `getc`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
 printf("%s", buff);
```

`buff` is not a *string*. You can either

- define `buff` as two element array, `char buff[2] = {0};` and then use `buff` as a *string*.
- define `buff` as a single `char` (not an array), pass `&buff` to `read()` call and use `%c` format specifier to print `buff`.
- use `%c` and pass `buff[0]`.

To elaborate, `%s` format specifier expects an argument as a pointer to a null-terminated `char` array. In your case, `buff` is one element too short to hold an input (from `read()`) as well as the null-terminator. So, due to the property of `%s`, the out of bound access happens which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Thank you for this catch! I will keep this in mind in the future. I have tried your solution, but the problem still extist.

Answer (score 0):

I think that **one** of the problems you have is that you are writing `word[i] = buff[0]`, but `word` only ever points to a string constant, if anything at all (`""`, these are things you should **not** write to). You need to create a writable buffer to store the word.

I also don't see you ever resetting `i` to `0` when you complete a word, so it will be forever trying to append to the same place.

To address this, you could try changes like the following:

`char *word;` -> `char word[256]; /* NOTE: arbitrary max word size here, you will need to ensure that you don't overrun that */`

`word = "";` -> `word[i] = '\0'; i = 0;` /* reset the string */

**EDIT**: Also, using `strcmp` to compare a single character is broken here as it is not a null terminated string. Instead, just do something like `if(buff[0] == ' ')`

**NOTE**: I don't see you doing anything useful with this `word` buffer you are trying to assemble, you can probably just chop it entirely.